# Is it possible to add the same sublabel to different parent labels?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have different people who email me about the same subject, e.g, WBR and AIB both email me about HP201.  However, so far as I can see Google only allows the sub-label HP201 to be attached to one parent.  Aside from making HP201 a parent itself is it possible to make it a sub label of WBR and AIB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A label can only have one parent (or no parent).

You could probably make two different "HP201" labels to put under their respective parents.

Really, though, you have a use-case for *not* having "HP201" as a sub-label. It should be a label unto itself. That way you can easily find all of the "HP201" conversations, "WBR" conversations, and "AIB" conversations. A quick search (`label:HP201 label:WBR`) will easily find the conversations with both labels.

Comment: I suspected that would be the answer, thanks! I am familiar with the  SEARCH facility but how would I search both labels at once as you suggest?

Comment: Just like I wrote it: `label:label1 label:label2`.

Comment: Yes thanks.  Sorry to sound incredibly stupid but which of the boxes would I enter the label info in? "Subject", "Has the Words" etc?

Comment: Just type in the search box. _Don't_ hit the down arrow on the right (which opens up the advanced search dialog).

Comment: If you've already got the dialog open, you can use the "has the words" field.